# Google Plus Content Recommendations for Mobile - Recommendations bar not showing

Tags: google-plus

We have implemented Google+ Content Recommendations for Mobile on our website. We followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/+/web/recommendations/.

We verified that we have the Javascript API on the page and that it has the correct Google+ Page ID.

However, the recommendation bar is not showing. We've tested several pages on our site.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the [troubleshooting information about when the recommendations bar is not showing](https://developers.google.com/+/web/recommendations/#recommendations_bar_is_not_showing), it says:

> - Low traffic sites might have few +1s, so there might not be enough available content to display. If you do not already use the +1 button, consider adding it to your pages.
> - Ensure that you are using canonicalization on your pages to help Google accurately count +1s.

The first item is the most likely reason that you don't see the bar. How large is your site? Do you have lots of +1s and plenty of other pages with +1s within your domain?

If you can provide the URL to your site, that can help further diagnose the issue.